# Convert SYSTEM DATE to YYYY-MM-DD and use it inside single quotes inside a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the system date and store it inside a variable and use that inside single quotes as a value inside a query

```
DECLARE @Tdate VARCHAR(20);

SET @Tdate = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());

SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Seymr 
WHERE BatchCreated BETWEEN '@Tdate 00:00:00.00' AND '@Tdate 05:00:00.00'
```

I get the following error - what is the correct syntax to use `@Tdate` inside single quotes?

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need such syntax, you need to use the *correct* types - date, datetime2 etc, not strings.

Assuming `BatchCreated` uses a date-related type, you can use :

```
declare @from datetime2(0)=cast(getdate() as date)
declare @to datetime2(0)=dateadd(hour,5,@from)

select count(*) from Seymr 
where BatchCreated between @from and @to
```

Comment: If one of the answers solved the problem, please consider marking one of them as the solution, @manket . This means future readers know the answer was helpful. Also, as a new user, getting reputation to use some of the basic functions is really important, and you get reputation for marking a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* what you are *really* after is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Seymr
WHERE BatchCreated >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
  AND BatchCreated <  DATEADD(HOUR,5,DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0,GETDATE()),0))
```

This shows you 2 ways to make `GETDATE` show the current date a midnight. The first is `CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` (should be quite obvious).

The second, however, uses some date math. It first gets the number of dates between the date `0` (`1900-01-01`) and `GETDATE()` and adds that many days to the date `0` (`1900-01-01`).  Then I add 5 hours to that `datetime`.

The reason I don't use `DATEADD(HOUR, 5, CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` is because this would generate an error:

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 5, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()));
```

> The datepart hour is not supported by date function dateadd for data type date.